# Antd: how to make a SubMenu be a clickable link?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, antd

I'm working on a Next.js app and I'm using antd's Menu and Submenu for my NavBar, and I'm trying to figure out how to make SubMenu be a clickable link. What is the way to do this?

```
<Menu className={styles.menuContainer} mode={mode} dashed={false}>
    <Menu.Item key='setting:1'>
      <Link href='/About'>About</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
    // have this point to '/resources'
    <SubMenu key='SubMenu' title='Resources'>
      <Menu.Item key='setting:2'>
        <Link href='/blog'>Blog</Link>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key='setting:3'>
        <Link href='/faq'>FAQ</Link>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key='setting:4'>
        <Link href='/events'>
          Events
        </Link>
      </Menu.Item>
    </SubMenu>
  </Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **to="#"** instead of **href="#"** when linking. As follows:

```
<Link to='/about'>About</Link>
```

Comment: OP is most likely using the built-in [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) from Next.js. `href='/About'` is the correct way to pass the `href` value.

Comment: Yeah, It's my fault to think that he is using react-router/link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this attribute

```
<Link href='/About' passHref><a>About</a></Link>
```